# Access properties in custom UIVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I created Custom UIView with bunch of labels. label1, label2,

```
UIView *testContentView = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"testContentView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

How do I access the label and setting text ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define them on your interface.

```
@interface TestContentView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;

@end
```

And then...

```
testContentView.label1.text = @"foo";
testContentView.label2.text = @"bar";
```

**Edit**

Added `IBOutlet` to the properties since you are using a NIB, you will also need to wire these up in Interface Builder.

Comment: it wouldn't work because it has been instantiate as UIVIew not TestContentView

Comment: You are correct, you need to use a custom sub-class of UIView. Sorry for overlooking that simple detail. I guess I assumed you had a subclass named `TestContentView` hence the reason my example of the interface is `@interface TestContentView : UIView`

Comment: I am not sure what you're saying. I updated the answer though to address that you are using a NIB. Bottom line is that you need a subclass of UIView to add properties to it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your custom properties, you need to cast the UIView to a TestContentView.

```
TestContentView *testContentView = (TestContentView *)[[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"testContentView" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```